# Add the scores using perl with its respective person

Tags: arrays, perl, matrix, file-handling

I have a file which contains data with many persons & their scores. i am trying to take avg of scores of each person.

```
Person 1
Scores (\
"0.06, 0.01, 0.07, 0.07, 0.75", \
"0.05, 0.08, 0.01, 0.09, 0.08", \
"0.10, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12, 0.10", \
"0.18, 0.19, 0.20, 0.20, 0.19", \
"0.31, 0.32, 0.32, 0.33, 0.32");
}
Person 2
Scores (\
"0.06, 0.01, 0.07, 0.07, 0.75", \
"0.05, 0.08, 0.01, 0.09, 0.08", \
"0.10, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12, 0.10", \
"0.18, 0.19, 0.20, 0.20, 0.19", \
"0.31, 0.32, 0.32, 0.33, 0.32");
}
```

Expected Output

```
Person 1 - (avg value)
Person 2 - (avg value)
```

What i tried:

```
open($in, “<file.txt>”)
    or die;

while(<$in>) {
    if (/Person/) {
        if (/Scores/../}/) {
            $_ =~ s/,//g;
            $_ =~ s/\\//g;  # removing all unwanted characters to take avg of numbers 
            $_ =~ s/"//g;
            $_ =~ s/values//g;
            $_ =~ s/\(//g;
            $_ =~ s/\)//g;
            $_ =~ s/;//g;
            $_ =~ s/}/ /g;
            @a1 = split(" ",$_);
        }
    }
}
```

After this point i am not able to store the values in array for further computation.

Comment: That's an unusual data format. What's producing it?

Comment: is it producing like some kind of a table or a matrix. Not sure but it looks like that.

Comment: So is the tabular data shown on the question accurate?

Comment: Yeah its correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental problem with your code is you are walking a line at a time through your input data, but you code is making the assumption that all the parts you need to parse the code are present in that one line.

For example these two statements are checking first for the literal `Person` on the current line, and then checking for the literal string `Scores` *on the same line*. That will never match -- the two literal strings are on different lines

```
    if (/Person/) {
        if (/Scores/../}/) {
```

There are lots of approaches to this problem, here is one of them.

```
use strict;
use warnings ;

use List::Util qw(sum);


# read the complete file into $data
my $data ;
{
    local $/;
    $data = <DATA>;
}

# repeatedly match each Person/Scores section
while ($data =~ /Person\s+(\S+)\s+Scores\s+\((.+?)\)/smg)
{
    my $person = $1;
    my $scores = $2;

    # now split $scores into the individual values - store in @scores
    my @scores;
    while ($scores =~ /(\d+\.\d+)/smg)
    {
        push @scores, $1
    }

    # @scores now holds the individual values. 
    # Can work out the average from them
    my $average = sum(@scores) / scalar @scores;

    print "Person $person - $average\n";
}

__DATA__
Person 1
Scores (
"0.06, 0.01, 0.07, 0.07, 0.75", 
"0.05, 0.08, 0.01, 0.09, 0.08", 
"0.10, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12, 0.10", 
"0.18, 0.19, 0.20, 0.20, 0.19", 
"0.31, 0.32, 0.32, 0.33, 0.32");
}
Person 2
Scores (
"0.06, 0.01, 0.07, 0.07, 0.75", 
"0.05, 0.08, 0.01, 0.09, 0.08", 
"0.10, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12, 0.10", 
"0.18, 0.19, 0.20, 0.20, 0.19", 
"0.31, 0.32, 0.32, 0.33, 0.32");
}
```

output is

```
Person 1 - 0.1744
Person 2 - 0.1744
```

### How the DATA filehandle works

The `DATA` filehandle is automatically opened against the current script file. Its file pointer is set to the line directly after the line that begins with `__DATA__`. I've used that to store the data you had in `file.txt`.

For example, assume the scriipt `test.pl` contains this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while (<DATA>)
{
    chomp;

    say uc $_ ;
}

__DATA__
alpha
beta
gamma
delta
```

running that script gives

```
$ perl /tmp/data.pl
ALPHA
BETA
GAMMA
DELTA
```

The use of the `DATA` file handle is super-convenient for creating a fully self-contained test script. Means you aren't dependent on an extra file.

Comment: `$data = <DATA>;` this in you code is <DATA> contains input file ? please clarify how you read input file

Comment: You need to have `__DATA__`on first line of your input file. In case if i am not able to edit it.?

Comment: No - there is no  explicit input file --  `__DATA__`  line is part of the perl script itself. Updated the answer again to clarify

Comment: Why are you using `local $/` what does it do ?

Comment: The magic variable `$/` is used to set the input record separator (which defaults to newline)  that gets used when Perl reads  a line of text from a file. Setting it to  undefined in this usecase means it will read the complete file in one invocation of `<DATA>`. See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$/ for the gory details.

Answer (score 2):

Based on provided data structure we can utilize `}` as record separator, it simplifies the task.

Then it is just a matter of extracting pieces of information from each block and make simple computation.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

$/ = '}';

while( my $record = <DATA> ) {
    next unless $record =~ /Person (\d)/;
    my $data;
    $data->{person} = $1; 
    $data->{scores}->@* = $record =~ /(\d\.\d{2})/gsm;
    $data->{sum}       += $_ for $data->{scores}->@*;
    $data->{count}      = scalar $data->{scores}->@*;
    $data->{average}    = $data->{sum}/$data->{count};
    say "Person: $data->{person} - ($data->{average})";
}

exit 0;

__DATA__
Person 1
Scores (\
"0.06, 0.01, 0.07, 0.07, 0.75", \
"0.05, 0.08, 0.01, 0.09, 0.08", \
"0.10, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12, 0.10", \
"0.18, 0.19, 0.20, 0.20, 0.19", \
"0.31, 0.32, 0.32, 0.33, 0.32");
}
Person 2
Scores (\
"0.06, 0.01, 0.07, 0.07, 0.75", \
"0.05, 0.08, 0.01, 0.09, 0.08", \
"0.10, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12, 0.20", \
"0.18, 0.19, 0.20, 0.20, 0.19", \
"0.31, 0.32, 0.32, 0.33, 0.32");
}
```

Output

```
Person: 1 - (0.1744)
Person: 2 - (0.1784)
```

Comment: I'm getting `Use of uninitialized value in division (/) at /tmp/pl line 15, <DATA> chunk 3.
Illegal division by zero at /tmp/pl line 15, <DATA> chunk 3.` . Not quite sure why

Comment: Your edit fixed the issue

Comment: It is difficult to say what causes it without seeing your actual input data. You can upload sample data somewhere on internet and then give a link to uploaded file.

Comment: I was using the first iteration of your posted solution. Problem gone now so all is well.

Comment: What method are you using in your code `-> {      }` is it hashes ?

Comment: @flash `$data->{key}` it is a reference to a hash. It is a very flexible way to create quite complicated data structure. You just create a reference which will be utilized to build a hash which will be referenced by this variable. Hash can include other structures as array `scores` or other hashes if such need exists.

Comment: @flash I have altered my code to __beatify__ it a little bit in more modern way, but if old version of Perl utilized it might cause an error -- in such case `@{$data->{scores}} = $record =~ /(\d\.\d{2})/gsm;` would be a solution.

Comment: I am not familiar with this method can you give some websites to learn more about referencing a variables or the methods you just used.

Comment: @flash Please read following documentation [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref). You might find very valuable a free online book [Modern Perl 4e](http://www.nylxs.com/docs/modern-perl-fourth-edition_p1_0.pdf) describing modern style of programming. If you do not mind to look at old Perl books which still good to learn Perl programming then [Perl bookshelf](https://www.google.com/search?q=perl+bookshelf) will uncover how to program for network communication, web data harvesting and much more.

Comment: @flash An answer to your question can be found in [Advanced perl programming: Data References and Anonymous Storage](https://www.google.com/search?q=Advanced+perl+programming%3A+Data+References+and+Anonymous+Storage).

Comment: @flash In case of any doubt, [Perl documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/) is just a click away. It will give answer practically to any question, take your time to investigate the structure of the documentation -- it will save you a lot of time in the future, you will know what section your question belongs to and jump directly to the information in the question.

Answer (score 2):

One way, as a command-line program (copy and paste at a prompt in most shells)

```
perl -MList::Util=sum -0777 -wnE'
    %p = /Person\s+ (\S+) \s+ Scores \s+ (.+?)(?=Person|$)/gsx; 
    for (keys %p) { 
        @n = $p{$_} =~ /[0-9.]+/g; 
        say "Person $_: ", sum(@n)/@n 
    }
' person_score.txt
```

This reads the whole file into a string (by `-0777` [switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#Command-Switches)), which is then available in `$_`.

In that string, match `Person` and capture what follows up to `Scores`, then capture all after `Scores` up to the next `Person` (or end of string) using a [lookahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind).  This captures a Person id and a substring that contains their scores.  Repeat that through the whole string (by modifier `/g`), thus matching all such pairs.

Such a list, made up of all *person-id* + *string-with-scores* pairs, can be assigned to a hash. Then pairs of consecutive strings in that list (*person-id* and the corresponding *string-with-scores*) make up key-value pairs in the hash.

Once we have such a hash it's easy. For each entry in the hash the numbers (scores) are extracted from the string with scores and assigned to an array, then used to get the average.

This works as it stands when all `Person`s are unique. If `Person` id's repeat in different sections this would have to be modified, to read lines one at a time so that separate records with same `Person` id can be merged and not overwritten.

---

Or write this as a program to put in a file, indeed better

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use List::Util qw(sum);

my $file_content = do { local $/; <> };

my %p = $file_content =~ 
    /Person\s+ (\S+) \s+ Scores \s+ (.+?)(?=Person|$)/gsx; 

for my $id (keys %p) { 
    my @scores = $p{$id} =~ /[0-9.]+/g; 
    say "Person $id: ", sum(@scores)/@scores 
}
```

This is run as `program-name filename`

---

*Explanation for `do { local $/; <> }`*

The `$/` variable is the [input record separtor](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$/); normally the newline character.  If it gets "unset" then all input is "one record" (for that Perl program).  Now, the following [<> operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators) reads files with names given on the command line, one line at a time ... or, really, one "record" at a time.

So when we unset `$/` and do `<>` then the whole file is read at once, "slurped." Then that is assigned to a variable since [do](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do) block returns whatever is last returned by a statement in it.

Finally, the [local](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local) makes it so that the change to `$/` (getting unset) persists only in the current block. Otherwise, it'd be changed for the whole interpreter, for all parts of the program.

So this little "idiom" of sorts is a way to read the whole file as a string, into a variable.

There are other ways, of course, and a good one to mention is to use a library

```
use Path::Tiny;  # path()

my $content = path($file)->slurp;
```

Here we need the filename (`$file`), can't use Perl's "magic" `<>`.  (We could use [@ARGV](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#@ARGV) which holds command-line arguments, so could say `path($ARGV[0])` or `path(shift)` when the filename is the first argument given on the command line.)

See links for relevant documentation.

Comment: Why are you using `local $/` what does it do ?

Comment: @flash  Added an explanation to the end of the answer